# Regular expression extracting last element starting with &[?

Tags: regex

The regular Expression should be applied to the following string:

```
[Product].[Product Catalog].[Product].&[50]&[53]&[DE]&[1ST_HQ]&[50_54_36]
```

As-Is:
The following regular Expression is applied:

```
(?:&\[).+(?:\])
```

That Returns:

```
&[50]&[53]&[DE]&[1ST_HQ]&[50_54_36]
```

To-Be:
I want to Change that regular expression to return

```
&[50_54_36]
```

only.
Any Idea?

Comment: Which regex engine / language are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use the end of the string `$` anchor if you want to extract the last element. Implementing Non-capturing groups for those characters is not necessary, so you can remove the groups as well.

```
&\[[^]]+]$
```

**Explanation:**

```
&        # '&'
\[       # '['
 [^]]+   #    any character except: ']' (1 or more times)
]        # ']'
$        # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vG6lH3/2)

Alternatively, I would suggest using a capturing group to match and capture the match result. The `.*` here will eat up all characters up until the last occurrence of `&[`. You can then refer to group `#1` for your match.

```
.*(&\[[^]]+])
```

Comment: Disappointed I didn't think of this..morning SO'ing doesn't work to well.

Comment: Great solution, should also note that `[^]]+` is also used instead of `.+`, so it requires the last group to not contain the `]` character.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
.*\K&\[.+\]
```

The `.*` instructs the regex engine to match all, then backtrack to match, so our match will start from the end of the string backwards and match the last. `\K` keeps the match afterwards.

See a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/fS8uH3/1)!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PCRE (or Ruby), you can do a dot-match-all and then backtrack to the last match of the `&[...]`. Throw away stuff to the left with `\K`:

```
.*\K(?:&\[).+(?:\])
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/nN9vZ9/1)

---

For an engine that doesn't support `\K`, you can use a repeated capture group. This requires you to turn the `.+` into a lazy repetition with a `?`. The capture group will contain the contents of the last instance captured. This will match `&[50]&[53]&[DE]&[1ST_HQ]&[50_54_36]`, but capture group 1 will equal `&[50_54_36]`:

```
((?:&\[).+?(?:\]))+
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/nN9vZ9/2)

Comment: While this approach (and mine) works slightly slower than the other answers anchoring the match for this specific case, the advantage is that the backtracking allows for an accurate match even if the object contains the `]` character, or isn't at the end of the string. See: `foo&[bar]baz` and `foo&[bar]baz]`. `&[bar]` and `&[bar]baz]` can be matched at ease.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a lookahead and replace `.+` with `[^\[\]]+`

```
&\[[^\[\]]+\](?=$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hS7nI7/2)

Comment: You don't need a lookahead.  `(?=$)` is exactly the same as `$`.

Comment: @AlanMoore yep i know that. Hwnd beated me by some seconds.